Logical replication issue in AWS RDS Postgresql
I am trying to set up PostgreSQL's inbuilt logical replication from one AWS RDS instance to another. A new user was created for this -
CREATE ROLE my_replication WITH 
    NOSUPERUSER
    NOCREATEDB
    NOCREATEROLE
    INHERIT
    LOGIN
    NOREPLICATION
    NOBYPASSRLS
    CONNECTION LIMIT -1;
GRANT rds_replication TO my_replication;

When I login to the database and execute
CREATE PUBLICATION my_publication FOR TABLES IN SCHEMA schema1, schema2....;

I get an error
 ERROR:  permission denied for database mydb

I have already connected to mydb as my_replication. PostgreSQL version is 16.3. What additional permissions are necessary?

I was able to fix that specific error by
  GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE mydb TO my_replication;

But it turned out that more privileges were necessary. "To add a table to a publication, the invoking user must have ownership rights on the table. The FOR ALL TABLES and FOR TABLES IN SCHEMA clauses require the invoking user to be a superuser." - from documentation
